# telnet to fetch sms from fakesmsc in kannel

Tags: python, unicode, sms, kannel

I have a test python application that pulls sms's from kannel fake smsc using telnet:-

```
cmd = '(sleep .5;echo 6666 7777 text ;sleep .5;) | telnet localhost 10000'
code, response = commands.getstatusoutput(smart_str(cmd, strings_only=True))
return HttpResponse(content=response, content_type="text/plain")
```

Messages containing roman characters show fine but unicode characters show as ???? marks.

The smsbox log has the text right:-

```
2015-07-13 14:36:03 [3751] [3] INFO: smsbox: Got HTTP request </cgi-bin/sendsms> from <127.0.0.1>
2015-07-13 14:36:03 [3751] [3] INFO: sendsms used by <kannel>
2015-07-13 14:36:03 [3751] [3] INFO: sendsms sender:<kannel:CLIPPD> (127.0.0.1) to:<911111111118> msg:<अगर
2015-07-13 14:36:03 [3751] [3] DEBUG: Stored UUID 24a89307-cd46-4e0b-b153-4ed0a9c46de6
```

And this shows fine too:-

```
return HttpResponse(content=u'\u0905\u0917\u0930', content_type="text/plain")
```

So the problem is more likely with processing via telnet:-

```
cmd = '(sleep .5;echo 6666 7777 text ;sleep .5;) | telnet localhost 10000'
code, response = commands.getstatusoutput(smart_str(cmd, strings_only=True))
```

I have also tried telnet -L but to no effect.

I am clueless about the need for telnet here the source of this problem. Please help.

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/adammck/pykannel ?

Or is that mandatory to use telnet + bash?

Comment: That sounds good. Could you make that an answer please.

Comment: Have you tried to encode the content as utf-8?  return HttpResponse(content=response.encode('utf-8'), content_type="text/plain")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use https://github.com/adammck/pykannel ?

Or is that mandatory to use telnet?